# Can a number have more than one identity element in a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let a*b=ab+a+b in R, can i say, the identity element is Zero in this BO if another number like -1 have more identities.
For example:
0*-1=-1 but 3*-1=-1
(Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Certainly $0$ is an identity, on either side (well, the operation is commutative),  And identities are unique!  If, say, $e$ were another identity  then we'd have $e=e\star 0=0$.

Comment: Though I'm not sure I have understood your question.  If $a=-1$ then, for any $b$ we have $-1\star b=-b-1+b=-1$ so any element is an inverse to $-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE! If in a ring $R$ there are two unit elements $e,e'$, then $e=ee'$ since $e'$ is a unit element, and $e'=ee'$ since $e$ is a unit element. This holds additively and multiplicatively.